# What does " Dark Emotions" means?

Tags: meaning

I have read a poem . In this poem , I am not very sure the meaning of "Dark Emotions" . The poet have written like that - "Dark Emotions were torn ever so deep". Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some circles, "dark emotions" refers to emotions like grief, fear, despair.  For example, a book by [Miriam Greenspan](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=healing+through+the+dark+emotions&x=0&y=0) is called ***Healing Through the Dark Emotions: The Wisdom of Grief, Fear, and Despair***.   [Some people](http://quizilla.teennick.com/quizzes/145415/a-look-at-your-dark-emotion-not-a-happy-quiz-has-pictures-and-6-detailed-results) include other negative (or not-positive) emotions such as anger, jealousy, apathy in the list of "dark emotions".

Partial context of the line you quoted (from Donna Solitario's *[The Poet's Heart](http://thebookmarketingnetwork.com/profiles/blogs/the-poet-s-heart)*) is as follows.

> ...
>   Often a dark room is lit by an enlightened candle
>   With faith, hope, love, and even peace
>   ...
>   Dark emotions were torn ever so deep
>   Tucked within the shell of its own body
>   Yet, the poet's heart can make even a dead spirit come alive

Even given this context, it isn't clear to me what the author means by "dark emotions".  That she might be referring to grief is suggested by "dead spirit"; that she is not  referring to anger, jealousy, fear, apathy is slightly suggested by references to faith, hope, love, peace.  But it is all quite unclear.  She might instead mean hidden emotions, which is consonant with "torn ever so deep", a phrase that's otherwise hard to fathom.